# MySQL Boolean Search include field inside inner join

Tags: mysql, boolean-search

how do we include in a boolean search the fields from an inner join?
I have these tables:

**Resume:**

```
   id
   user_id
   job_title
   job description
   location_id  (linked to country id)
```

**Country**

```
id
iso_code_2
iso_code_3
name
```

what i want is to search for data that has Manager or Head but not have the text Philippines.

I am assuming this text will work:  'Manager Head -Philippines'
but it doesnt.

Do i need to "copy" the country name into a filed in Resume?

This is currently my Query:

```
  select resumes.*, 
  MATCH (resumes.job_title, resumes.job_description) AGAINST ('Manager Head -Philippines' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance_1,
  MATCH (countries.name) AGAINST ('Manager Head -Philippines' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance_2
  LEFT JOIN countries ON countries.id = resumes.location_id
```

Comment: Please show some sample data and the expected output, as well as any query you may have already tried.

Comment: hi @TimBiegeleisen, i added my sample code.

Comment: Are you actually using full text search?

Comment: Yes I am.  Basically I am creating a search system where a user (a paying customer) can use AND OR NOT inside the search field.  similar to most JOB sites.

Comment: Your first call to `MATCH` looks fine to me.  But why, in the second call to `MATCH`, are you expecting that manager or head would appear in the country name?  That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: That's what I want to change actually.  I want to update that code so that when Manager Head -Philippines is searched, the job_title, job_description fields and the country name field will be searched correctly.  Should I add a country_name field into Resume?  This is my current proposal but was hoping there is another way.

Comment: The resume and country tables are already connected via a key relationship, so why don't you just check the country name from the `Country` table, after doing a join?  Full text search is expensive, and you should probably avoid it if you can (though when dealing with resumes, you probably can't, at least not completely).